# kaptKotlin not recognizing micronaut options

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kapt

I'm trying to setup a micronaut project.
The project is using Gradle and Kotlin.

I'm using the Micronaut CLI to generate the project, but after the initial setup with the CLI I'm getting this warning:

```
> Task :kaptKotlin
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[micronaut.processing.incremental, micronaut.processing.module, kapt.kotlin.generated, micronaut.processing.annotations]'
The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[micronaut.processing.incremental, micronaut.processing.module, kapt.kotlin.generated, micronaut.processing.annotations]'
```

I've used this command to setup the project:
`mn create-app com.my.example --build=gradle --lang=kotlin`

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.32"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.32"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.5.3"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.32"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.my"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.my.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.my.ApplicationKt")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("14")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "14"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "14"
        }
    }


}
```

Micronaut version: 2.5.8

Java version: 14

Gradle version: 7.0

Kotlin version: 1.4.32

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: What version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь I'm using Gradle 7.0. I've updated my post :)


`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-bin.zip`

Comment: You're referencing to `kotlinVersion` variable. It's defined as `val kotlinVersion = "1.4.32"`, right?

Comment: Yes, Kotlin 1.4.32.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're using correct version of JVM for compilation, try to replace `java { sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("14") }` with `java { toolchain { languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(14)) } }`.

Comment: Thanks - I've just tried it. Same warning appears.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь, any other suggestions?

Comment: There was a similar issue in their github (https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/5218), but it was marked as fixed in micronaut 2.4.3. Maybe it's a regression/incomplete fix? Try to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve created an issue now: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/5772 

Comment: The same here happened to me. Micronaut 3.2.0, multi-project gradle. Dang.